# Showing how much time a user spent on a certain activity in a textview

Tags: java, android, timer

I want to have a timer on, say, XActivity, and record how much minutes and seconds spent on that XActivity from Oncreate to its end by calling finish(); and show that recorded time on a textview in, say, YActivity, which starts after XActivity is killed. I know how to pass data with intent and all. I just need to have some inspiration about timer.

Comment: There have to be a million questions about getting system time in java here on StackOverflow. Please search for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign System.currentTimeMillis() to a variable in onCreate.

Take the difference of System.currentTimeMillis() and the variable when the activity ends.

This will get you the time spent in the activity in milliseconds.

Answer (score 3):

Inside the onCreate method assign current time to a variable as follows :

```
final long Start = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

similarly when the activity ends, get the current time again :

```
long End = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

and calculate the difference :

```
long timeElapsed = End - Start;
```

Please note that the elapsed time is calculated in milliseconds, divide by 1000.0 to convert to seconds.